# Extract the email addresses from a block of text containing strictly formatted, delimited values

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, text-extraction

I have an ICS file that will be uploaded in my server when a meeting created in google calendar, yahoo calendar, etc.... I have parsed date, organizer, etc,. from the ics file. But i can't able to get the attendees list. Below is the code will be in the ICS file.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT

ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:xxxxxxx

  xx@xxx.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:yyy@yyy.com

ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:zzz@zzz.com

ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:aaa@aaa.com

CLASS:PUBLIC
```

From the above code, I need the email ID's associated with mailto parameter. Please help me to achieve this.

```
<?php
$cal = file_get_contents("ics_files/outlook.ics");
$cal = str_replace("\n", "", $cal);
preg_match_all('/mailto:(.*?)ATTENDEE/', $cal, $attendees);
?>
```

Comment: @Nenotlep I have tried regex. But it is not extracting what I want.

Comment: @VinayakInfotech: Then please post what you've tried so far along with the expected result and the results you're getting currently.

Comment: @AmalMurali I have added the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the pre-formatting line that removes newlines (`\n`) from the ics data, a straightforward regex can be used:

```
/mailto:(.*?)(?:ATTENDEE;|CLASS:)/s
```

The `/s` tells the regex-engine to match newline characters with the `.`. If you wanted to drop the `/s`, you could instead use:

```
/mailto:((?:\r\n|\n|.)*?)(?:ATTENDEE;|CLASS:)/
```

Using PHP's `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/mailto:(.*?)(?:ATTENDEE;|CLASS:)/s', $cal, $attendees);
```

The output:

```
print_r($attendees[1]);

Array (
    [0] => xxxxxxx

  xx@xxx.com
    [1] => yyy@yyy.com
    [2] => zzz@zzz.com
    [3] => aaa@aaa.com
)
```

You can then iterate over the `$attendees[1]` array and apply any email-address logic / formatting you wish.

Example:

```
foreach ($attendees[1] as $attendee) {
    // remove any extra spaces/newlines from the address
    $attendee = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", ' ', $attendee)));

    // split the address into any available name/email-address combination
    $address = explode(' ', $attendee);

    echo $address[0];
    if (!empty($address[1])) {
        // there is a name/email-address combination available
        echo ' <' . $address[1] . '>';
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
xxxxxxx <xx@xxx.com>
yyy@yyy.com
zzz@zzz.com
aaa@aaa.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You're removing all the newline characters from your file  and thereby making everything in a single line. Since `.*?` matches any character that's not a newline character (non-greedy match), you'll get emails that contain a space too - for example, `xxxxxxx  xx@example.com` will be matched.

You could get a little bit more specific and limit the regular expression to just match (and capture) `mailto`: followed by anything that's not a space, followed by any space character (could be a tab, newline, or a different space character):

```
preg_match_all('/mailto:(\S+)\s/', $cal, $attendees);
print_r($attendees[1]);
```

This will return the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xxxxxxx     /* <--- not valid */
    [1] => yyy@yyy.com
    [2] => zzz@zzz.com
    [3] => aaa@aaa.com
)
```

However, these are all not still valid e-mail addresses. If you also want to validate these e-mail addresses and filter out those that are not valid, you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) validation as a callback - it's easier than using a regex to achieve the task.

```
if ($match) {
    $valid_emails = array_filter($attendees[1], function ($email) {
        return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    });
}

print_r($valid_emails);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => yyy@yyy.com
    [2] => zzz@zzz.com
    [3] => aaa@aaa.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex,

```
/ATTENDEE.*mailto:(\S+)/g
```

It'll only match all attendee's mail to

Comment: Just a note: PHP does not have a `g` modifier - you use `preg_match_all` to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
preg_match_all('/mailto:(.+)/', $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: This code will return all starting from mailto:. But I need exact email ID in an array.

Comment: No it returns all the email ids only. Mailto is not there. Check again